# Return at least X rows (null rows till count of rows is X) when query returns no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a way to get at least X rows? Even when the query returns 0 rows. 
Example, if a table has 3 rows total, how can i do a SELECT TOP 10 from that table and return 3 rows that has data in it and 7 rows that are all nulls?

I looked around quite a bit but couldn't find the exact answer I was looking for. 
I'm using SQL Server 2012
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will need to use a numbers table as a starting point.  Then you can left join to the numbers table in order to achieve this result.

```
WITH CTE_numbers AS (--using a cte as an example of a numbers table
SELECT 1 as rn
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3)
,
cte_Top as(--Query to select top X number of records
SELECT TOP 3 'testdata' r,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY column) as rn
FROM Table)

SELECT *
FROM CTE_numbers cb
LEFT JOIN cte_Top ct
ON cb.rn = ct.rn
```

This should give you the correct number of rows even if the query that uses 'TOP' does not have the equal amount of rows in the result. I used top 3 instead of top 10, but you can change the query to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

One method just appends 10 empty rows and then chooses 10 rows from the entire result set:

```
select top 10 t.*
from ((select top 10 t.*, 0 as which from t)
      union all
      (select t.*, v.n
       from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) v(n) left join
            t
            on 0 = 1
      )
     ) t
order by which;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a row over function first, then joined on the table later. Worked like a charm. Thank you for the help!